# How to click a Button which is located under a Shadow-Root

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, shadow-dom, shadow-root

Hey so I am trying to click a Button which is located in a Shadow-Root, I am new to this topic and this is my first time working with Shadow Roots.

**The Website:**
https://www.all4golf.de/?gclid=CjwKCAjw67ajBhAVEiwA2g_jEP_x3w6PJibWICIaE61LtLDJO_EEy85mgKRseNvZIAJpsA4Qw1yQMBoCOpkQAvD_BwE

Some Information: I am working in Visual Studio Code on a Mac, C# using Selenium and the Chromedriver. Opening Chrome and clicking and filling Textbooks out of the Shadow-Root works.

Thanks in Advance for your Help!!

I also tried to use the driver.executescript but I can't manage to get it working, it says that something with the executescript is missing (beginner problem I guess).

Result should be that the Accept (Akzeptieren) Button will be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, If you are using selenium version > 4 , it has native shadow dom support

```
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.all4golf.de/?gclid=CjwKCAjw67ajBhAVEiwA2g_jEP_x3w6PJibWICIaE61LtLDJO_EEy85mgKRseNvZIAJpsA4Qw1yQMBoCOpkQAvD_BwE");
    IWebElement root = driver.FindElement(By.Id("usercentrics-root"));
    ISearchContext shadow = root.GetShadowRoot();
    IWebElement accept = shadow.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".sc-eDvSVe.eDuWYU")); 
    accept.Click();
    // Quit the driver
    driver.Quit();
```